# iPhone GPS app not showing current location on tester phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, gps

I have an iPhone GPS application that uses Google Maps SDK to show the user current location on a map within the app (my app does not open the Google Maps app).
The user can then mark points on the map based on their current location which is then saved to a database.

I can view my current location on my iPhone that I use for testing and I can also mark and submit points (lat/long coordinates). I am distributing the app app to another tester using Crashlytics but when they run the app on their phone they don't see their location marked on the map (no blue dot displayed of their current location). And when they mark a point on the map, the point is saved as 0,0 - the same as if you were to test the app on the emulator and no location has been set up.

I have deleted my app on my phone that was installed when I run it via Xcode and have installed the same version via Crashlytics I have sent them via Crashlytics. When I run it on my phone then I still see my location and can log the current location as the correct lat/long.

I have asked them to check if location services are enabled on their phone and they have said that they are.

Is there any reason that can cause them to not see their location on the map? I have also tested on my iPod Touch and I can even see my location on that. Its just the tester that does not see their location at all.

I am testing on an iPhone 4 and they are testing on an iPhone 5 - but I don't think this should make a difference? Also my iPod is the latest generation and that shows my location.

Has anyone else come across this situation and what could be the possible cause/fix?

Comment: Hmmmn....I don't see a reason for it to work on your device, and not work on theirs. Besides the general location service, there is also an app-related location service access, that you could deny an app from using the location services, while still leaving it on. If the first time they run the app and been notified that the app want to use their current location, they could've chosen "Don't allow", which won't grant your app access to the location services, even if they are on. It's on the same menu of the location services. ask them to check it.

Comment: BTW- are you both using the same iOS version?

Comment: I have asked them to double check the location services again - in particular the individual app location permissions. Hopefully this is the issue that global permissions are set to allow but the individual app is set to deny, otherwise Im completely stumped. As for iOS versions, I am on 7 on my iPhone 4 (cant upgrade to 8) and 8 on my iPod Touch while they are on 8 on their iPhone 5.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. They have check individual app permissions and still its not picking up their location. Still setting their location as 0,0.